# Cygwin: xwin scaling broken when using windows scaling on high resolution display

Tags: linux, ssh, cygwin, x11, xterm

Using a laptop with a 4k screen and windows scaling turned on so that text looks the same size it would on a 1080p display.

When I open cygwin and run `startxwin` xwin starts but at the resolution of the 4k display, not the scaled down 1080 resolution. Worse, when I connect another monitor i.e. a 2560x1440 display and make that the main display, now when I run startxwin it generates an xterm window on that new display but scaled down ***below*** the native resolution of the monitor so that it looks the same size as it did on the 4k native resolution (it's rendered with 4 times fewer pixels and looks awful).

What this tells me is that xwin is capable of scaling, but the configuration is wrong. Looking through documentation for xwin, I can't find a reference to scaling and I didn't really want to become an expert on xwin just to get my x terminals to appear the right size.

Does anybody know cygwin's xwin package well enough to provide a scaling how-to?

If not, does somebody have a better way of spawning multiple terminal sessions through a single ssh session? (i.e. how you can launch as many x windows as you want through a secured ssh session)

Comment: I don't know why this is being downvoted. I present a problem and ask for either a direct or indirect solution. Managing X-Windows across SSH from a windows machine is unavoidable where I work because the company laptops are all windows, but the servers we do our work on are all linux.

Comment: This question is offtopic here. It has nothing to do with programming. For questions about using general purpose software see http://superuser.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of `/etc/X11/Xresources`, which has a line `Xft.dpi: 96`.
You can override this with a `~/.Xresources` file containing just `Xft.dpi:`

(At least that's what the problem was for me!)

Comment: That doesn't seem to make my tiny fonts any bigger.